# Calling Java function from Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino, phonegap-cli

Calling Javascript functions running inside Rhino from Java is easy enough - that after all is why Rhino was created.  The thing I am having trouble establishing is this:

- **Context**: I have a Phonegap CLI (v 6.3.3) Android project (API 19+) where I do a great deal of processing via loadable JavaScript running inside rhino
- A Phonegap plugin - which I am creating at the same time as the actual Phonegap app - contains class called `Storage` which provides public, static, methods such as `readFromFile(String fileName)`, `writeToFile(String fileName,String data)` etc.
- What I want to be able to do is to call `Storage.readFromFile` etc from my loaded JavaScript code in Rhino.

Just how this should be done is not too clear to me.  From the searches I have done thus far it involves using `ScriptableObject.putProperty` to pass the Java class in question, `Storage` in my case to JavaScript.  However, how this should be done and then how it should be used at the JS end leaves me rather confused.

I would be most grateful to anyone here who might be able to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that Rhino has less than 100 followers here it should perhaps come as little surprise that this question was not answered.  In the mean time I have managed to find the solution myself and it turns out to be very simple.  I share it below for the benefit of anyone else running into this thread.

My `Storage` class is very simple.  It goes something like this

```
public class Storage
{
 public static boolean haveFile(){}
 public static boolean readFromFile(String fname){}
 ...
}
```

When I call Javascript from Java via Rhino I simply pass a new instance of the `Storage` class as the last of my function parameters

```
Context rhino = Context.enter();
Object[] functionParams = new Object[] {"Other parameters",new Storage()};
rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);
try 
{
 Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
 String rhinoLog = "var log = Packages.io.vec.ScriptAPI.log;";
 String code = /*Javascript code here* as shown separately below/;
 rhino.evaluateString(scope, rhinoLog + code, "ScriptAPI", 1, null);
 Function function = (Function) scope.get("jsFunction", scope);
 Object jsResult = function.call(rhino,scope,scope,functionParams);
}
```

where the Javascript code is

```
function jsFunction(a,s)
{
 //a - or a,b,c etc - here will be the "other" parameters
 //s - will be the instance of the Java side Storage class passed above
 //now you can do things like
 s.writeToFile('fileName','fileData');
 var fd = s.readFromFile('fileName');
 s.dropFile('fileName');
 ...
}
```

Comment: I have noted that this question has recently got the "popular question" badge.  For the benefit of future visitors to this question.  Rhino is 20 year old technology.  You are better off using a more modern ES6 compatible scripting engine.  There are many alternatives such as [Duktape](https://github.com/square/duktape-android) and [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8).  In terms of raw performance J2v* is a tad better but that comes at a price - the size of the APK.  I personally now use Duktape.  Follow the links on the Squareup Github page for Duktape for integration information.